# Random freeze of the desktop environment

Tags: freeze

I have an old laptop running Ubuntu Mate 22.04 LTS that randomly freezes on the desktop environment. It happens most of the times while I am watching a movie or a video on YouTube, but no idea what is the trigger of it.

It is an old HP Laptop from around 2014 that has an Intel Pentium 3540 (2.4 ghz), 8 GB of RAM (2  dual channel), 500 GB HDD.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.